# Open source e-commerce solution for a tool catalog based around EAV

Tags: magento, attributes, e-commerce, entity-attribute-value, catalog

I'm looking for an e-commerce system that is built around EAV (entity-attribute-value) somewhat like Magento, but hopefully simpler. I'm really okay with just about any platform (Java, .NET, PHP, whatever), I just really need to be able to freely associate properties with groups of products... e.g. a drill bushing will have some inner diameter and outer diameter, a drill bit will have a certain outer diameter, etc. Thanks for the info!

Comment: Sane people don't use EAV - they value their data and EAV makes it extremely difficult (verging on impossible) to ensure the data's integrity.

Comment: @Johnathan Leffler: Sane people don't use EAV *without reason*. For retailers with complex attribute requirements, EAV is the most conceptually simple model short of adding multitudinous columns to a table (which is not extensible.) The poster appears to have such requirements.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any other ecommerce systems that use EAV (except Magento).  While Magento does have a learning curve, I think you'll find it worth the effort particularly if you start by working some of the improved documentation and tutorials written by Stack Overflow members like Alan Storm.